# Matrix equality conjecture

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

$T_1$ and $T_1$ are any real, square, lower-triangular, toeplitz matrices of dimension $p>1$.

Let $\left[
\begin{array}
 [c]{cc}%
 T_1 & T_2
\end{array}
\right]  _{\mathcal{B}}$ denote the $p\times p$ sub-matrix of
$\left[
\begin{array}
 [c]{cc}%
 T_1 & T_2
\end{array}
\right]  $  made up of the columns of $\left[
\begin{array}
 [c]{cc}%
 T_1 & T_2
\end{array}
\right]  $ determined by $\mathcal{B} :=\left[  i_{1}%
,i_{2},\ldots,i_{p}\right]  $.
The vector complementary to
$\mathcal{B},$ denoted $\mathcal{B}^{\ast},$ is the vector whose components
are the $p$ integers from $1,2,\ldots,2p$ not in $\mathcal{B}.$

Similarly, let $\left[
\begin{array}
 [c]{c}%
 T_2\\
 -T_1
\end{array}
\right]  _{\mathcal{B}}$ denote the $p\times p$ sub-matrix made up of the rows
of $\left[
\begin{array}
 [c]{c}%
 T_2\\
 -T_1
\end{array}
\right] $ determined by $\mathcal{B}.$

Define

$M_1=\left[
 \begin{array}
  [c]{cc}%
  T_1 & T_2
 \end{array}
 \right]  _{\mathcal{B}}$,
$M_2=\left[
 \begin{array}
  [c]{cc}%
  T_1 & T_2
 \end{array}
 \right]  _{\mathcal{B}^{\ast}}$,
$M_3= \left[
\begin{array}
 [c]{c}%
 T_2\\
 -T_1
\end{array}
\right]  _{\mathcal{B}}$
and
$M_4= \left[
\begin{array}
 [c]{c}%
 T_2\\
 -T_1
\end{array}
\right]  _{\mathcal{B}^{\ast}}$.

I conjecture that the following matrix identity holds:

$M_1M_3+M_2M_4 \equiv 0_{p \times p}$.

Is this result known ?

Answer (score 2):

I have just realised that it is very easy to show this. It follows from two elementary observations:

1. For any two matrices $A$ and $B$ of compatible size, the product $AB$ remains the same if the columns of A and the rows of B are permuted in the same way, and
2. Lower-triangular toeplitz matrices commute.

In the question statement
$\left[
\begin{array}
 [c]{cc}%
 M_1 & M_2
\end{array}
\right]$
is obtained from
$\left[
   \begin{array}
    [c]{cc}%
T_1 & T_2
\end{array}
\right]$ by a permutation of columns. The same permutation applied to the rows of $\left[
\begin{array}
 [c]{c}%
 T_2\\
 -T_1
\end{array}
\right]$ gives $\left[ \begin{array}
 [c]{c}%
 M_3\\
 M_4
\end{array}
\right]$.

Hence
$M_1M_3+M_2M_4 = T_1T_2-T_2T_1$ by 1).
But $T_1T_2-T_2T_1=0$ by 2).
So $M_1M_3+M_2M_4=0$ which was the conjecture statement.